Recommended project types for a simple recurring task hosted on Azure
We need to build a simple project that will retrieve and update data each 5 minutes from ZOHO via their API.
It will ultimately be hosted on Azure.
It won't need a UI.
What project type is recommended for this task?

You need to specify on what azure service you will host this. If it's Azure VM it could be a windows scheduler task and a simple exe, if Azure DevOps you can use Pipeline and just a powershell script .. it can vary greatly

I would recommend a timer-triggered azure function. It´s easy to use. You can use different languages and it has good pricing models.

After different considerations, I opted for a console application hosted on Azure as a webjob.
